# How to get first derivative of the complex function with matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am trying to implement Perram-Wertheim overlap potential algorithm which I basically need for ellipsoid overlap. I got stuck on evaluating first derrivative which author doesn't state.

The function I need to derivate:
$F[r(\lambda),\lambda] = \lambda(1-\lambda) r_{AB}^TCr_{AB} $

where $r_{AB}$ is a vector,
$C(\lambda) = [\lambda B + (1-\lambda)A]^{-1}$
A and B are matrixes 3x3

The second derivative
$\frac{d^2F[r(\lambda),\lambda]}{d\lambda^2} = -2r_{AB}^TC(\lambda)[\lambda A^{-1}+(1-\lambda)B^{-1}]C(\lambda)r_{AB}$

Evaluated with the help of:
$C(\lambda) = [\lambda B + (1-\lambda)A]^{-1}$
$r(\lambda)-r_A = (1-\lambda)ACr_{AB}$
$r(\lambda)-r_B = -\lambda BCr_{AB}$

There is another option, as I need it to find maximum of function F for
$\lambda$ in range <0,1> I can find unique root of the polynomial $h_{AB}=P_{AB}^{'}Q_{AB} - P_{AB}Q_{AB}^{'}$

$P_{AB}(\lambda) = \lambda(1 - \lambda)(a_{AB}^Tadj(\lambda I + (1-\lambda)A_{AB})a_{AB}$
$Q_{AB}(\lambda) = det(\lambda I+(1-\lambda)A_{AB})$

where
$a_{AB}=B^{1/2}r_{AB}$
$A_{AB} = B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}$

I have to mention that I am not a mathematican, I've got mathematics during my studies but it was quite a long time ago so please be patient and as simple as possible :) I need those computations in my C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 R &= r_{AB}r_{AB}^T\cr
 M &= B-A &\implies &C^{-1} = A+\lambda M \cr
 &\  &\ &dC^{-1} = M\,d\lambda \cr
}$$
Then we can write the function as
$$\eqalign{
F &= (\lambda-\lambda^2)R:C
}$$ where the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB).$

Taking the differential of the function
$$\eqalign{
 dF
 &= (1-2\lambda)\,d\lambda\,R:C + (\lambda-\lambda^2)R:dC \cr
 &= (1-2\lambda)R:C\,d\lambda - (\lambda-\lambda^2)R:C\,dC^{-1}\,C \cr
 &= R:\Big[(1-2\lambda)C + (\lambda^2-\lambda)CMC\Big]\,d\lambda \cr
}$$
yields an expression for the derivative, which can be rearranged to whatever form you prefer 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{dF}{d\lambda}
 &= R:\Big[(1-2\lambda)C + (\lambda^2-\lambda)CMC\Big] \cr
 &= R:\Big[(1-2\lambda)(A+\lambda M)^{-1} + (\lambda^2-\lambda)(A+\lambda M)^{-1}M(A+\lambda M)^{-1}\Big] \cr
 &= r_{AB}^T\Big[(1-2\lambda)(A+\lambda M)^{-1} + (\lambda^2-\lambda)(A+\lambda M)^{-1}M(A+\lambda M)^{-1}\Big]r_{AB} \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you Greg, it is great solution! I do not exactly understand all transformations you have done but if I need further explanation I will write here :)

Comment: Can I ask you also for the second derivative of 
$F[r(\lambda),\lambda] = \lambda(1-\lambda) r_{AB}^TCr_{AB} $   ? 

I know that I placed it on the top, but I think there is some misunderstanding in my analysis of the article.

Comment: I believe it's  $$\frac{d^2F}{d\lambda^2} = 2R:\Big[(\lambda^2-\lambda)CMCMC - C\Big]$$

Comment: Oops!  I missed a term and a sign:  $$\frac{d^2F}{d\lambda^2} = 2R:\Big[(\lambda-\lambda^2)CMCMC + (2\lambda-1)CMC - C\Big]$$

Comment: Thank you Greg, to be honest I get second derivative from another program and it is: $\frac{d^2F[r(\lambda),\lambda]}{d\lambda^2} = - R:[CACBC] + R:[CBCAC]$

Today I know it's correct, but don't have a clue why it looks like this, are there some thesis or laws in Math that gives explanation to this form of the derivative?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take it step by step

$$\frac{dF}{d\lambda}=(1-2\lambda)(r^T C r)+(\lambda-\lambda^2)\left(\frac{dr^T}{d\lambda}(Cr)+r^T \frac{dC}{d\lambda}r + r^T C \frac{dr}{d\lambda}\right)$$ etc

Comment: So if I am correct, $\frac{dr^T}{d\lambda}$ is 0 when r is a vector independent from $\lambda$, aren't I?

Comment: yes if r contains no $\lambda$ dependence, it'll have a zero derivative w.r.t. \lambda ... in this case you'd be left with only the middle term in the parentheses with 3 terms on RHS of RHS

Comment: what is the meta-application of this (the context behind the context in your first sentence)

Comment: Meta-application? If you ask where I need to use it, it is random requential addition of ellipsoids :)

Comment: I am still confused. Why we derivate r as it stands as Constant, shouldn't it be in second part $(\lambda-\lambda^2)(r_{AB}^T\frac{dC}{d\lambda}r_{AB})$ ?